# redirect to website after checking id from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect a web page only after checking the id from database table. How can i check dis using if condition or by calling procedure?

This is my code:

```
public partial class site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPropCode.Text != "")
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://real.com/Properties_Detail?id=" + txtPropCode.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Go]
(
    @Pid bigint 
)   
AS
    SELECT * from Properties where Id=@Pid
```

Comment: Inside button click, call stored procedure and check whether id exist or not then do redirect

Comment: @ Venkateswaran R.....bt it still not working....protected void btnLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button lnk = (Button)sender;
        cmd.CommandText = "Go";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pid", txtPropCode.Text);
        


        Response.Redirect("http://real.com/Properties_Detail?id=" + txtPropCode.Text);

    }

Comment: you want to check id exist in database or not.. Right, so what you want to do means before calling Response.Redirect(""), you have to call stored procedure and check the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by running the query in codebehind because its a single not complex query so there is no need to write a SP for this purpose. If you just need to verify whether the record exists, use ExecuteScaler method and verify the result whether exists or not, do it this way instead:

```
    protected void btnLink_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Properties where Id=@Pid", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pid",Convert.ToInt32(txtPropCode.Text));
        con.Open();
        object id=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        If((int)id!=-1);
        //it means record exists 
        else
        //The record doesn't exist
    }
```

Now its up to you chose if you want to redirect user when the record exists else don't redirect or whatever you need to do. Its tested code and it works.

Hope it helps!